# How can I display triangle faces (not quads) in Cinema4D?

Tags: 3d, web, mobile, low-poly, cinema-4d

I started to learn Cinema 4D. I've noticed it's really easy to use for motion graphics, but I want to use it for modeling for games/realtime 3d engines.

Before I used 3dsmax and it was easy to estimate how a model would look/behave in a 3d engine. The two main things I did was **displaying Polygon triangles** and **displaying the Polygon Count**.

I've found the Total Polygons tick in HUD settings in Cinema 4D, but I can't find any display mode that will show triangles.

Is there there a way to display triangle faces/not quads in Cinema4D ? If so how ?

There is a Triangulate function, but I'd rather not Triangulate/Untriangulate all the time, especially since it's converting back and forth between the two doesn't always produce the same result.

I imagine I'm asking for old school techniques, but I plan to use these to make low poly models for web(canvas/webGL) and mobile.

Comment: If you don't get an answer here, consider posting this to a place like http://www.polycount.com/forum/. If you get an answer over there, you can also post it here.

Comment: An artist named Psionic has made lots of game dev oriented tutorials about Cinema4D: http://www.psionic3d.co.uk/videos.html#cinema4d

Comment: check out these gathered resources for game art using C4d https://polycount.com/discussion/212367/cinema-4d-for-game-art-game-development-resources-c4d-vs-blender-or-max